# Paste as Values is wrong

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365

My Paste as Values is giving me a strange answer:

All cells have Number format

Cell L12: 123,139.10

Cell C12: 123,132.94

Formula: =C12-L12

Formula's answer: -6.16

Paste as values: -6.16000000000349

Why is the Paste as Values doing this?

Comment: Looks like a Float conversion error.  I'm not certain of the fix.  What happens if you copy the Formula Answer and paste into a separate Text file?

Comment: If you ROUND (Formula) the values (I do this) to 2 places, then when you copy and Paste Values, they will come out correctly